# Sticky positioned child ignores parent's padding

Tags: html, css, css-position

How can I prevent the sticky element from going behind the header?

The current snippet uses padding top on the parent, I tried also using margin-top on an extra child instead or transparent 50px border but it doesn't seem to work.

I know I can easily use `top: 50px;`  on the sticky in this case but I want to integrate this part in a React Component and using specific sizes make it harder to combine different Components since they all have to share the top size.

How can I make the header/padding  be "solid" and make the sticky unable to go through?

```css
body{
  background: rgb(200,200,200);
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
header{
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 2em;
  background: aqua;
  opacity: 0.6;
  text-align:center; 
  position: fixed; 
  width: 100%;
}
.content-wrapper{
  padding-top: 50px; /* keeps the header space */
  
  height: 800px; /*for demo*/
}
.sticky{
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="sticky">
  Hello, I am a sticky element
  <div>
<div>
```

Comment: I don't think there's an easy CSS solution to this (without hardcoding the `top`), but in React you could build a `<HeaderWrapper/>` of some sort that manages the offset of each its child elements.

Comment: But you are telling the sticky element to stick to the top when it  hits that position of the scrolled container therefore it should ignore the padding.  the best you could do would be to make the content container the thing that scrolled so the top would be relative to that instead of the body (and gave it margin top instead of padding top so it didn't go under the header)

Comment: @Pete Is there a way to keep the header space and make sticky position takes it into account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this has drawbacks I'm unaware of or if it is viable in your case, but `translateY` seems to work. It's definitely hacky though.

```css
body{
  background: rgb(200,200,200);
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
header{
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 2em;
  background: aqua;
  opacity: 0.6;
  text-align:center; 
  position: fixed; 
  width: 100%;
}
.content-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  height: 800px; /*for demo*/
  transform: translateY(50px);
}
.sticky{
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
}

.spacer {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="sticky">
  Hello, I am a sticky element
  <div>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting solution, the only disadvantage is when using percentage in the height but calc can easily solve it. I'll deeply test it later.